# Read data into array slices in R

Tags: arrays, r, csv, for-loop, matrix

How can I read large csv files into slices of an array in R?
I have like 500 csv files with 480 rows and 640 columns that contain data of a thermal imaging camera. What I would like to make is an array with dimensions 640 x 480 x 500 where in fact every slice of the array contains one picture taken by the thermal camera (640 x 480 pixels (values in °C)). Untill now I put the csv files in a list of matrices with a for loop and then unlist them to make an array. The problem with this is that my computers RAM is full so quickly so it might be better to store the data in an array at once, but I just don't know how to do that. I need the data in an array format anyway for further calculations.

```
matrices<-list()

for (i in 0:endval){
        filenumber<-sprintf("%03d",(i+1))
        matrices[[i+1]]<-read.csv2(file=paste(nameoffile,filenumber,".csv",sep=""),header=F)
        }

array1<-array(unlist(matrices), dim = c(nrow(matrices[[1]]), ncol(matrices[[1]]), length(matrices)))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The best way to format it probably depends more on how you're going to use it. I would probably opt to store it as a list of matrices without unlisting in most situations, but again it depends.

Comment: For most applications, the list of matrices does the job but at one point I have to take the mean an st.dev. over the z axis so the mean of all the 500 pictures. I found a way to do this for an array but not for a list of matrices.

Is it possible to extract one slice from an array to a matrix? If that's the case I would prefer to have the data in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should preallocate the array once, and then just fill in each z-slice as you loop through the CSV files. From my testing, it appears that a 640x480x500 array of doubles takes about 1.2GB, and 500 CSV reads each assigned directly to a z-slice of the array took about 3.5min. Thus, this is very tenable, in terms of both RAM impact and computation time:

```
X <- 640; Y <- 480; N <- 500;
write.csv(matrix(1:(X*Y),X,Y),'pic1.csv',row.names=F); ## for testing
system.time({ x <- array(NA_real_,c(X,Y,N)); }); ## preallocate
##    user  system elapsed
##   1.640   0.109   1.743
object.size(x);
## 1228800208 bytes
e <- 2; Xv <- -((1+e):(X-e)); Yv <- -((1+e):(Y-e)); Nv <- -((1+e):(N-e));
x[Xv,Yv,Nv];
## , , 1
## 
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
## [2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
## [3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
## [4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
## 
## , , 2
## 
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
## [2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
## [3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
## [4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
## 
## , , 3
## 
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
## [2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
## [3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
## [4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
## 
## , , 4
## 
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
## [2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
## [3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
## [4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
## 
system.time({ for (i in 1:N) { fileName <- 'pic1.csv'; x[,,i] <- as.matrix(read.csv(fileName)); }; });
##    user  system elapsed
## 207.000   0.969 208.492
object.size(x);
## 1228800208 bytes
x[Xv,Yv,Nv];
## , , 1
## 
##      [,1] [,2]   [,3]   [,4]
## [1,]    1  641 305921 306561
## [2,]    2  642 305922 306562
## [3,]  639 1279 306559 307199
## [4,]  640 1280 306560 307200
## 
## , , 2
## 
##      [,1] [,2]   [,3]   [,4]
## [1,]    1  641 305921 306561
## [2,]    2  642 305922 306562
## [3,]  639 1279 306559 307199
## [4,]  640 1280 306560 307200
## 
## , , 3
## 
##      [,1] [,2]   [,3]   [,4]
## [1,]    1  641 305921 306561
## [2,]    2  642 305922 306562
## [3,]  639 1279 306559 307199
## [4,]  640 1280 306560 307200
## 
## , , 4
## 
##      [,1] [,2]   [,3]   [,4]
## [1,]    1  641 305921 306561
## [2,]    2  642 305922 306562
## [3,]  639 1279 306559 307199
## [4,]  640 1280 306560 307200
```